# Identify individual months within quarters

Tags: expressions, dates

To identify months in 2-months-intervals one can use "odd months" and "even months".

How would one most concisely identify individual months within quarters (other than the obvious "every second month within each quarter", referring to February, May, August, November)?

Comment: I don’t think “*discern*” means what you think it means.

Comment: Identify, not discern.  These are the middle months of each quarter.  The names are shorter than your description.

Comment: There are only 3 months within each quarter. So 'every second month with each quarter would mean either the middle month or the months at the start and end of each quarter. I think what you're looking for is something along the lines of 'quarterly from February'.

Answer (score 1):

2 month intervals are special, because we have common English words (even and odd) for what mathematicians call [*arithmetic modulo 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)). There are no such words for *modulo 3*, so I suggest you use [@Xanne's suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396695/identify-individual-months-within-quarters#comment941351_396695):

- January, April, July and October are the *first* months of a quarter
- February, May, August and November are the *middle* months of a quarter
- March, June, September and December are the *last* months of a quarter

Comment: Residue-class-1-modulo-3-starting-with-January months? (Some 'years' start in April etc.)